# Django: User doesn't get assigned to an instance of a model

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and I have the following problem. When I login and create a company using the createCompany.html, the company gets created in the database but its 'user' attribute stays empty. The user attribute is supposed to be the user who is logged in and creating the company. What do you think is wrong with my code?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length = 100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)

    yontemler =(('3CNC', '3 eksen CNC'),('5CNC', '5 eksen CNC'),)

    imalatyontem = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=yontemler, null=True, verbose_name = 'İmalat Yöntemleri')

    industries =(('Imalat', 'İmalat'),('Kimya', 'Kimya'),('Hammadde', 'Hammadde'),)

    industry = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=industries, null=True, help_text='Sektörünüzü Seçin')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, city, user, imalatyontem, industry):
        company = cls(name=name, city=city, user=user, imalatyontem=imalatyontem, industry=industry)
        return company

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return models.reverse('company-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from .forms import CompanyCreationForm

def createCompany(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CompanyCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
            user = request.user
            imalatyontem = form.cleaned_data.get('imalatyontem')
            industry = form.cleaned_data.get('industry')
            Company.create(name, city, user, imalatyontem, industry)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = CompanyCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'createCompany.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Company

class CompanyCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'city', 'imalatyontem', 'industry']
```

createCompany.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form action="/createCompany/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <fieldset class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="controls">
                {{ field }}
                <p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }} </p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: remember to mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `create` classmethod is pointless; you should remove it. It doesn't save the object, which is then just thrown away.

The work of creating the instance is actually done by `form.save`, before you add the user. So you should use the standard pattern for this:

```
   if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        return redirect('index')
```